# как можно найти выведенный слова в инпут из текстареа с помощью джаваскрипт?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

Создать элемент Textarea. Поместите необязательный текст внутри этого элемента. Пусть элемент input будет размещен в другом отдельном блоке. Пусть определено, есть ли в тексте внутри textarea слово, записанное внутри элемента Input. При выполнении этой задачи вы можете использовать элементы цикла, события onclick или onkeyup.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function valid(e) {
  console.log(e)
  if (document.getElementById("ta").textContent.includes(e)) {
    document.getElementById("check").textContent="Есть"  
  } else {
    document.getElementById("check").textContent="Нет"  
  }
}
```

```html
<textarea id="ta">Хорошая лаба, Diyor</textarea>
<input onkeyup="valid(this.value)"/>
<span id="check">Нет</span>
```